# XSLT For-Each loop to get data from enumerated tags?

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I've been provided an SML file where the designer (not in my company, so I have no control over this) has created some data that I need to consume; but they setup enumerated tags, so I'm having a difficult time creating a loop to read the data.

Their code looks like

```
   <Root>
    <Subjects>
    <...more XML Data>
    <Data>
      <...other XML Data>
      <Demographic_Information>
            <Age1>33</Age1>
            <Age2>66</Age2>
            <Age3 />
            <Age4 />
            <Age5 />
            <Age6 />
            <Age7 />
            <Age8 />
            <Age9 />
            <Age10 />
            <Gender1>M</Gender1>
            <Gender2>F</Gender2>
            <Gender3 />
            <Gender4 />
            <Gender5 />
            <Gender6 />
            <Gender7 />
            <Gender8 />
            <Gender9 />
            <Gender10 />
            <Race1>W</Race1>
            <Race2>H</Race2>
            <Race3 />
            <Race4 />
            <Race5 />
            <Race6 />
            <Race7 />
            <Race8 />
            <Race9 />
            <Race10 />
        </Demographic_Information>
        </...other XML Data>
    </Data>
    </...more XML Data>
   </Subjects>
  </Root>
```

I just need to loop through this, and ensure that Age1, Gender1, and Race1 go into my data like

```
<Person subject="1">
    <Age>33</Age>
    <Gender>M</Gender>
    <Race>W</Race>
</Person>
<Person subject="2">
    <Age>66</Age>
    <Gender>F</Gender>
    <Race>A</Race>
</Person>
```

This is a subset of data inside a larger set, but I need to get it into this format if possible.  I'm sure it can be done, I just don't know how to go about it.

My XSLT is version 1.0 in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.  I start with

```
<xsl:template match="/Root/Subjects">
```

***Modified to provide a better sample of my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick stab that works - I'm going to continue to look at this to find efficiencies, but I wanted to get you an answer.

**EDIT: thanks to @MartinHonnen for a nice simplification.**

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable
     name="vNums"
     select="'0123456789'"/>

  <xsl:key
     name="kElemByNumber"
     match="Demographic_Information/*"
     use="translate(name(), translate(name(), $vNums, ''), '')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Demographic_Information>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="*[generate-id() = 
                  generate-id(key(
                    'kElemByNumber',
                    translate(name(), translate(name(), $vNums, ''),
                    ''
                  ))[1])][normalize-space()]">
        <xsl:sort
          select="translate(name(), translate(name(), $vNums, ''), '')"
          data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Demographic_Information>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <Person subject="{position()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="key('kElemByNumber', position())"
        mode="children">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Person>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="children">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(name(), $vNums, '')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the provided source XML:**

```
<Demographic_Information>
  <Age1>33</Age1>
  <Age2>66</Age2>
  <Age3/>
  <Age4/>
  <Age5/>
  <Age6/>
  <Age7/>
  <Age8/>
  <Age9/>
  <Age10/>
  <Gender1>M</Gender1>
  <Gender2>F</Gender2>
  <Gender3/>
  <Gender4/>
  <Gender5/>
  <Gender6/>
  <Gender7/>
  <Gender8/>
  <Gender9/>
  <Gender10/>
  <Race1>W</Race1>
  <Race2>H</Race2>
  <Race3/>
  <Race4/>
  <Race5/>
  <Race6/>
  <Race7/>
  <Race8/>
  <Race9/>
  <Race10/>
</Demographic_Information>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<Demographic_Information>
  <Person subject="1">
    <Age>33</Age>
    <Gender>M</Gender>
    <Race>W</Race>
  </Person>
  <Person subject="2">
    <Age>66</Age>
    <Gender>F</Gender>
    <Race>A</Race>
  </Person>
</Demographic_Information>
```

Comment: +1. Nice, I had the same key idea. But I think `<Person subject="{translate(name(), translate(name(), $vNums, ''), '')}">` can be simplified to `<Person subject="{position()}">`.

Comment: Excellent observation, @MartinHonnen - thank you! I will update.

Comment: Absolute geniuses!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @ABach: Really great flexible solution Took me a while to understand.

Comment: Thank you, @hr_117, I appreciate it! Let me know if there's any clarity I can provide.

Comment: So, just one issue.  I am using Visual Studio 2008 to get this done.  It keeps telling me that xsl:key "Variables cannot be used with this expression".

Comment: That's a shame. In that case, merely replace the variable reference with the actual value: `<xsl:key name="kElemByNumber" match="Demographic_Information/*" use="translate(name(), translate(name(), '0123456789', ''), '')"/>`

Comment: completely works for the sample xml given.  I guess I should have been more clear.  I've been trying to modify this for my purposes for the last couple of hours.  I have the given xml inside a larger xml file, and I have a very large XSLT doing all the work.  I'll modify my sample above to provide a better idea of what's going on, but I can't seem to get the sample to wrok if I modify it and teh xml to look more similar to the XML I'm trying to trnslate.

Comment: @Mac-Gon - ask a new question (so that this one isn't polluted) and let me know - I will answer it.

Comment: @ ABach : About to post now.

Answer (score 0):

another alternative:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet
   version="1.0"     
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Demographic_Information">
        <Demographic_Information>
            <xsl:for-each select="./*[starts-with(name(), 'Age')][normalize-space()]">
                <xsl:variable name="i"><xsl:value-of select="string(position())"></xsl:value-of></xsl:variable>
                <Person>
                    <xsl:attribute name="subject"><xsl:value-of select="$i"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <Age>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
                    </Age>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[starts-with(name(), 'Gender')][position()=$i]"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[starts-with(name(), 'Race')][position()=$i]"/>
                </Person>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Demographic_Information>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'Age')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'Gender')]">
        <Gender>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </Gender>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'Race')]">
        <Race>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </Race>
    </xsl:template>


   <!-- defaults -->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The `<xsl:value-of select="./position()">` instruction throws an error.

Comment: it doesn't with me - which xslt processor do you use ? mine is altova /xslt2. however, it does if i use the /xslt1 option ... ;-)

Comment: If only we all had XSLT/XPath 2.0, life would be so much easier. :(

Answer (score -1):

The following will do. But perhaps not the fastest solution.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[substring(name(),1,3) = 'Age']">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="substring(name(),4)"/>
        <Person id="{$id}">
            <Age><xsl:value-of select="."/></Age>
            <Gender><xsl:value-of select="//*[name() =concat('Gender',$id)]"/></Gender>
            <Race><xsl:value-of select="//*[name() =concat('Race',$id)]"/></Race>
    </Person>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This does not produce the wanted output; it includes all of the empty `<Person>` elements that, based on the OP's requested output, should be omitted.

Comment: @ABach: Yes you are right; I did not thought this was the point. Could easily be adapted. But your solution is far better and far more general, any way.